# JS - Insert php tag inside a div on click

Tags: javascript, php

first off I know that php is server side and js is client side.

What i want to do is depending on the button i press the include changes to a diffetent file inside the div.

```
<div id="theOne">
    <?php include("file.php"); ?>
</div>
```

I want to change the name of the filewhen i press a button.
Is that even possible?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: you can easily do that but that won't be executed  and the file won't be included

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI what do you suggest i do instead of this, to display the page and change what page it display on click